# EventLog "Access Denied" after installing an additional DC in a 2012 environment

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-event-log

After promoting a new DC into an existing domain, Eventviewer shows the following:

[image]

I might as well mention that the Installation itself did not experience any issues

When looking at the C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs directory I do not see any entries related to AD\DFS\DS etc. Also comparing the permissions on the folder with a working DC did not show any differences.

Comment: Did you reboot the DC after the promo? Does powershell command "get-addomain" show the name of the new DC in the ReplicaDirectoryServers property? What does running event viewer locally on that server show beneath the "Application and Services Logs" node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by doing the following:

- Going to C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs.
- Re-taking ownership for the System account and applying on all files and folders.